# "Statement cannot be just an expression." -error using $CmdLine

Tags: autoit

```
$CmdLine[0]
$CmdLine[1]

If Not FileExists($CmdLine[1]) Then
    DirCreate($CmdLine[1])
EndIf
```

With this line from the command prompt it works just fine:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe" folder-test1.au3 "C:\SomeFolder"
```

When I compile it into an EXE it gives me an error on each of the
`$CmdLine` lines:

> error: Statement cannot be just an expression.

Why?

Comment: Like it says, a statement can't be just an expression. If you remove those lines, it should compile and work fine. What are you trying to accomplish with those two lines?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DanielHaley I was trying to make an exe that I can use a parameter with `folder-test1.exe "C:\test"` so it will pass the "C:\test" to the `$CmdLine`. I was just confused a bit by the help on the `$CmdLine`

Comment: @Eric CmdLine is an [Array](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Arrays) that stores the parameters that you pass to your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use following script (remove first 2 lines from your script):

```
if not FileExists($CmdLine[1]) Then
    DirCreate($CmdLine[1])
EndIf
```

Then you should compile it to .exe and run. (If you are edit you script with SciTe editor, then you can compile in Tools-Compile menu)